# How to set different row height in listfield?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

Closed. Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573850/how-to-set-different-row-height-in-listfield-with-implementing-listfieldcallback/11644420#11644420). Thanks

Comment: you cant do it. you can only set a fixes height.

Answer (score 1):

There is undocumented method `setRowHeight(int row, int height)`. But no one guarantees that it will be there with next OS update. More details [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/ListFields-setRowHeight-int-int-Method/td-p/558556).

Modify you TableRowManager like this:

```
private class TableRowManager extends Manager {
    private int row;

    public TableRowManager(int row) {
        super(0);
        setRow(row);
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    ...
    ...

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return getRowHeight(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try method setRowHeight(int row, int height)?

Comment: I use this setRowHeight(x, int height)

Comment: Maybe because this:     public int getPreferredHeight() {return getRowHeight();} You should probably use height of current row. I also don't understand why you use preferredWidth if you get actual width already. Also it's not optimal to call layout every time.

Comment: Don't understand. Where do you want to set index?

Comment: `getRowHeight(index)` in `getPreferredHeight()`

Comment: Maybe you could set it in constructor and keep it as class field. And have setter if order is changed. Or you could call setter every time when you paint row. Or better to use height that you get from paintRow argument